# How to deal with 'expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ImageFieldFile' while loading image to Keras?

Tags: python, django, tensorflow, keras

edit: changed title and body of question

I am following a tutorial to build a small image classification app and am coming into a problem when I reach the try/except block. @Nicolas Gervais pointed me out to how to display the traceback, and you can see below that `exc >>>>>> expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not ImageFieldFile` returns from the exc.

```
from django.db import models
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array

class Image(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField()
    classified = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Image classifed at {}".format(self.uploaded.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            print('self.picture >>>>>>> ', self.picture)
            img = load_img(self.picture, target_size=None)
            img_arr = img_to_array(img)
        except Exception as exc:

            print('traceback >>>>>>', traceback.format_exc())
            print('exc >>>>>>', exc)
            print('classification failed')

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

The image gets saved fine to the database, but it the code when I am using 'load_img' doesn't work (as the print statement below it does not run)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print error to screen but continue code execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834172/print-error-to-screen-but-continue-code-execution)

Comment: that sure is helpful! i'm going to edit my question to show the traceback